# Exchange 2007/2010 migration dilemma

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange-2010, exchange-migration

I've run into a dilemma, not sure of the best way to tackle it.

Here's how I got to where I am now.

- We had an Exchange 2007 setup previously in Site A
- I recently installed Exchange 2010, also in Site A
- SSL certificate was purchased, etc. basically everything was set up and I was ready to move mailboxes
- For various reasons it was decided that Exchange 2010 should be run from Site B instead

I thought this should be no problem, I can uninstall Exchange 2010, leaving 2007, then simply install 2010 in Site B, no problem.

Except for the problem:

- I can't uninstall Exchange 2010, because there are arbitration mailboxes in the Exchange 2010 mailbox database.
- I cannot move these to the 2007 server because arbitration mailboxes on a 2010 mailbox database and "can't be move to versions of Exchange earlier than Exchange 2010"

So..... is there some way I can install Exchange 2010 in Site B while its still installed in Site A, but still use the same public-facing DNS name for OWA/EWS/etc? Or must I use a different name and write off the cost of the SSL certificate that would no longer be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I was needing to do that I would:

- Install Exchange 2010 in site B
- Migrate any 2010 mailboxes to this server
- Decommission Exchange 2010 server in site A
- Setup DNS records to point records for the old 2010 server to the new one
- Setup the SSL cert on new server
- Profit!